# Invalid Column in SQL SubQuery

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am trying to run a query below and I am getting the following errors and unable to figure out.

Please look at how column `AllocPer` is being calculated. That's where the errors are coming from:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure USP_RS_Dealio_JLL_ECRDetails_test, Line 688
>   Invalid column name 'dealid'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure USP_RS_Dealio_JLL_ECRDetails_test, Line 689
>   Invalid column name 'empid'.

My SQL code:

```
SELECT 
    MarketPerDiff, CommissionDate, empid, dealid 
INTO
    #vwDealEmpSplitDetail_Emp 
FROM 
    dbo.vwDealEmpSplitDetail_Emp

PRINT 'Query 1 Starts at ' + CONVERT(nvarchaR(36), getdate(), 114)
SET@ t1 = GETDATE()

SELECT
    Per.enddate "CommEndDate",
    'Period ' + CAST(Per.Period AS VARCHAR) "SubPeriod",
    Col.EligibleDate AS "CollectionDate",
    Col.DealID,
    Client.clientName,
    Deal.DealName,
    Col.EmpID AS "ProfID",
    Emp.FullName AS "ProfName",
    SUM(ISNULL(Col.CashCollected, 0)) CashCollected,
    Stat.MarketID,
    Stat.OpUnit,
    HB.Description,
    SUM(ISNULL(Col.CostHurdle, 0)) AS "DEmpCostHurdle",
    ISNULL(Prof.DealCostMultiplier, 50)[DealCostMultiplier], 
    (SELECT SUM(MarketPerDiff) "MarketPerDiff"
     FROM #vwDealEmpSplitDetail_Emp 
     WHERE #vwDealEmpSplitDetail_Emp.dealid = Deal.DealID AND 
           #vwDealEmpSplitDetail_Emp.empid = Emp.EmpID) as AllocPer
INTO 
    #SummedValues
FROM 
    tblEmpCollectionAdj Col WITH(NOLOCK)
JOIN 
    tblDeal Deal WITH(NOLOCK) ON Deal.DealID = Col.DealID
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.tblClient Client WITH(NOLOCK) ON Client.ClientCode = Deal.ClientCode
JOIN 
    tblMktOpUnitCompStatus Stat WITH(NOLOCK) ON Stat.BatchID = Col.BatchID
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.tblEmployee Emp WITH(NOLOCK) ON Emp.EmpID = Col.EmpID AND Emp.Active = 1
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.tblCommPeriod Per WITH(NOLOCK) ON Col.EligibleDate BETWEEN Per.StartDate AND Per.Enddate
LEFT JOIN 
    tblEmpCompProfile Prof WITH(NOLOCK) ON Prof.EmpID = Col.EmpId 
                                        AND Prof.Active = 1
                                        AND Prof.PeriodID = @PeriodId
                                        AND Prof.Batchid = Col.Batchid
LEFT JOIN 
    tblHBAlloc HB ON HB.HBAcctEmpID = Prof.EmpID 
                  AND HB.OpUnit = Prof.OpUnit
                  AND HB.CF3 = Prof.MarketId 
                  AND HB.FiscalYear = @Year1
WHERE 
    Col.Active = 1
    AND Deal.Active = 1
    AND Col.PeriodId = @PeriodId
    AND ISNULL(Col.CashCollected, 0) + ISNULL(Col.CostHurdle, 0) NOT BETWEEN - .01 AND.01
GROUP BY
    Per.enddate,
    'Period ' + CAST(Per.Period AS VARCHAR),
    Col.EligibleDate, Col.DealID, Client.clientName,
    Deal.DealName,
    Col.EmpID,
    Emp.FullName,
    Col.CashCollected,
    Stat.MarketID, Stat.OpUnit,
    HB.Description,
    ISNULL(Prof.DealCostMultiplier, 50), 
    deal.dealid, Emp.empid, Per.StartDate, Per.Enddate

PRINT 'Query 1 Ends ' + CONVERT(nvarchaR(36), getdate(), 114)
SET@ t2 = GETDATE()
PRINT ' TIME ELAPSED ' + CAST(DATEDIFF(millisecond, @t1, @t2) AS NVARCHAR(255))
```

Comment: Presumably you are using a case-sensitive database collation and `empid` should be `EmpID`

Answer (score 1):

The error should be self-explanitory. It seems that you are referencing a column that does not exist in a table you are trying to access it from. Without access to your table structure, unfortunately we can only guess at the issue. However, your error says that the columns `dealid` and `empid` are invalid. I see that they are being used in several places.

Check to ensure that `dealid` exists in the following tables/views: `tblEmpCollectionAdj`, `vwDealEmpSplitDetail_Emp`, `tblDeal`.

And check that `empid` exists in the following tables/views: `vwDealEmpSplitDetail_Emp`, `tblEmpCollectionAdj`, `tblEmployee`, `tblEmpCompProfile`.

Also, a point that @Blorgbeard mentioned in a comment, check that you are using the proper casing for the column and for table aliases. You have the table `tblDeal` aliased as `Deal`, however you reference it as `deal` in at least one place.